# How to make requests from the client IP

Tags: php, ajax, ip

I'm developing a web application that parses a third party site and makes POST and GET requests to it.
Problem is that this will be used by different registered users and I need the requests not to come from the web server but from each client IP.
I wanna make it in PHP/ajax. Is it possible to do this, basically avoid that all the requests come all from the same IP (being the web server that runs php)?

If not what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, this is impossible.

To understand why, replace `third party site` with `bank` or `company intranet`.

Comment: if I make it with a windows program?

Comment: A regular program can do whatever it wants to, as long as you convince your users to install it.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement the code on the client side using javascript and consume the thrid party app directly, you can do this. On the server side, there is of course no way to fake a IP that way.

Comment: Well, if there is an API and I get data via a HTTP_Request (POST or GET, as stated in the question), I can do a http request with ajax from a javscript and then use the response. I don't see why I would not be able to do this. Any API (e.g. facebook) works like that.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to read data from a different domain.  (Except with JSONP, which is what APIs use)

Comment: That's true, I got your comment wrong. Will change my answer accordingly.